# Resharper shows 'Wrong name case' for XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, resharper, scrollviewer

I have a weird issue that I'm not sure what to make of with ReSharper.  I have a solution that has been working fine but lately it decided there were '11 errors in 2 files'.  However when I look at them here is what it has:

One style dictionary (xaml file) contains 9 errors that say 'Wrong name case'.  When I look at them they are all something like `{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}` and the portion it's underlining with this error is `ScrollViewer`.  The others are various ScrollViewer properties but all are ScrollViewer and that's the part it's complaining about.

A separate style dictionary shows 2 errors.  Both of them are basically the same binding as above but the error this time is "'ScrollViewer' is not public".

I did do some reorganization of files and namespaces recently but neither of these files were touched...

The really odd thing is that it builds just fine and doesn't seem to have an issue running, but I can't get the errors to go away.  I have also tried restarting VS as well as a 'drop all and reanalyze' in R# to see if it was some type of weird caching but it still comes back.

So what happened to my solution that R# would start showing this?

P.S. I did Google around about this with the error message and R#, etc. but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: Is Resharper reporting an error, a warning, a message or a code issue.  Most of the time, Resharper issues are "code issues".  They have rules about how things should be named and used.  You can disable the message or disable the rule

Comment: It's showing it as an error, plus when I alt-enter on it I don't get the normal options to rename or anything like that.  It's also a .NET type so I couldn't really rename it if I wanted to...